# Using while loop to repeat a step of loop to reach the proper answer

Tags: python, if-statement, random, while-loop

I have the following code which I just write the final part of it. For some reasons we use `random.normal` values. As it is obvious the `func` function has three variables.

My question is: The steps of calculations is `101`and exactly we have `100` values for each parameter in output. How should I tell Python, If you see `Wo[i]>0` and `Omo[i]<0` recalculate that step (which would use another random number) until we have the proper answer `(Wo[i]<0 and Omo[i]>0`.

***We have to do this because***, If we print outputs and then remove those values which do not satisfy our condition, we have for example, 60 values instead of 100. I know we can use `while loop` but I do not know how.

```
N=101
for i in range (1,N):
    R=np.random.uniform(0,1)

    Omn[i] = Omo[i-1] + 0.05 * np.random.normal()
    Wn[i] = Wo[i-1] + 0.05 * np.random.normal()
    Mn[i] = Mo[i-1] + 0.1 * np.random.normal()

    L = exp(-0.5 * ( func(Omn[i], Wn[i], Mn[i] ) - func( Omo[i-1], Wo[i-1], Mo[i-1] )))

    if L>R:
        Wo[i]=Wn[i]
        Mo[i]=Mn[i]
        Omo[i]=Omn[i]

    else:
        Wo[i]=Wo[i-1]
        Mo[i]=Mo[i-1]
        Omo[i]=Omo[i-1]

    print(Wo[i],Mo[i],Omo[i])
```

Comment: `while(found == false)` when you reach the proper answer `found = true `??

Comment: `while Wo[i]>0 and Omo[i]<0: # calculate again` ?

Comment: @MoeA I did this, but Python is just thinking and does not print anything

Answer (score 0):

You can use a normal while loop and check the condition after calculating, for example:

```
for i in range (1,N):
    R=np.random.uniform(0,1)
    while True:
        Omn[i] = Omo[i-1] + 0.05 * np.random.normal()
        Wn[i] = Wo[i-1] + 0.05 * np.random.normal()
        Mn[i] = Mo[i-1] + 0.1 * np.random.normal()
        if Wo[i] <= 0 and Omo[i] >= 0:
            break
    # rest of code
```

Comment: I did this, but Python is just thinking and does not print anything and does `break` repeat the calculation? or stop it?

Answer (score 0):

Insert a `while` loop to repeat the calculations you require.

When `L > R`, `Wo` and `Omo` are updated with the `Omn` and `Wn` values. So if this values are `Omn<0` or `Wn>0` you need to re-calulate them. 
When `L <= R`, `Wo` and `Omo` are calculated from the previous iteration. Since the previous iteration already is `Wo[i]<=0` and `Omo[i]>=0` you don't need to repeat those calculations.

Thus, as shown in the code below, you only need to re-calculate the Omn and Wn variables:

```
Omo[0] = 0.24
Wo[0] = -0.2
Mo[0] = 1.0

N = 101
for i in range (1,N):
    is_valid = False
    if __debug__:
        print "Calculating position " + str(i)
    while (not is_valid):
        Omn[i] = Omo[i-1] + 0.05 * np.random.normal()
        Wn[i] = Wo[i-1] + 0.05 * np.random.normal()
        Mn[i] = Mo[i-1] + 0.1 * np.random.normal()

        if __debug__:
            print "- is_valid iteration values: " + str(Wn[i]) + " " + str(Omn[i])
            print "- is_valid previous values: " + str(Wo[i-1]) + " " + str(Omo[i-1])

        is_valid = Omn[i] >= 0 and Wn[i] <= 0 

    R = np.random.uniform(0,1)
    L = exp(-0.5 * ( func(Omn[i], Wn[i], Mn[i] ) - func( Omo[i-1], Wo[i-1], Mo[i-1] )))

    if L > R:
        Omo[i] = Omn[i]
        Wo[i] = Wn[i]
        Mo[i] = Mn[i]
    else:
        Omo[i] = Omo[i-1]
        Wo[i] = Wo[i-1]
        Mo[i] = Mo[i-1]

    print(Wo[i], Mo[i], Omo[i])
```

Comment: I did this, but Python is just thinking and does not print anything

Comment: That's because the `Wn[i]>0 and Omn[i]<0` condition never mets. Maybe your starting value Wo[0] and Omo[0] are set incorrectly? You can try to add `print(Wn[i], Omn[i])` before the `is_valid` assignment to debug it.

Comment: there are random numbers and in each running of the code we may have different numbers of negative value for `Om`. Due to this, I wanted my code as it sees a negative value for `Om` repeat that step until it has a positive number then it can go to next step. I got stuck in this part and I don't know how to solve it

Comment: I understand that but if `Omo[0] = 20000` you will unlikely get a negative number with `Omn[i] = Omo[i-1] + 0.05 * np.random.normal()`. So, can you provide the output of a run adding the `print` I suggested you right before the `is_valid` assignation?

Comment: I have added some debug prints in the code. Can you provide the output or the way you initialize `Omo[0]`, `Wo[0]` and `Mo[0]`?

Comment: I have also updated the `is_valid` condition since I re-readed your post and I understand that the values ARE valid when `Wn[i] <= 0 and Omn[i] >= 0`

Comment: `- is_valid iteration values: 0.19294352519277874 0.2431022561471791
- is_valid previous values: 0.2 0.24
- is_valid iteration values: 0.21603937782506638 0.23038956514374828
- is_valid previous values: 0.2 0.24
- is_valid iteration values: 0.2024672962691261 0.23784637442038042`  Python print it continuously. infinite ouputes

Comment: So, as I told you, there is no way to make `Wn[i] <= 0` with the randomization you made. Maybe you  should adjust the values something like: `Wn[i] = Wo[i-1] + 0.2 * np.random.normal()` ? Or you can change your Wo[0] value to something negative already?

Comment: when in the end of the code `print` can see negative and positive values, there should be a way to customizing the outputs according their calculations. It is out of my knowledge and I did hope to find a solution here.

Comment: Sure, after many iterations you could get negative numbers. The problem is that if you wish that all entries accomplish Wn[i]<=0 and Omn[i]>=0 the first entry (Wn[0], Omn[0]) must already accomplish it. So, instead of modifying your randomization, can you provide the way you initialize the 0 values?

Comment: `Omo  = np.zeros((101,))
Omo[0]=0.24`  I initialized the 0 value and similar to other values

Comment: I have added some initial values that work fine for me. As you see, the `Wo[0]` value must be negative and `Omo[0]` positive!

Comment: My code has initial values. your code print out these values without end.

`0.2 0.24
0.18229338401946607 0.2566770022430132
0.2 0.24
0.2099542090065686 0.25705528738296296
0.2 0.24
0.21215552390367606 0.2403385230423422
0.2 0.24
0.21044593776027842 0.2215775377668842
0.2 0.24
0.20742859448201306 0.23991129544222142
0.2 0.24
0.20066774250803 0.22496669115338586
0.2 0.24
0.20268861309697347 0.25658882586354964
0.2 0.24
0.21167478196195877 0.24197546075667367
.......` But it does not print the last `print` which work with two `if statement`

Comment: Should I ask a new question in stackoverfllow?

Comment: Your code has initial value Wo[0] = 0.2 and Omo[0] = 0.24. This two values do not accomplish the premise of Wo <= 0 and Omo >= 0 and the randomization you are following will never get you Wo[1] negative because you are multiplying by 0.05. Thus, it is not a problem of the code I am providing, its a problem of a) Your initial value b) Your randomization factor. Either you choose Wo[0] = -0.2, either you use 0.2 as randomization factor.

Comment: The code will print out the values without end because you cannot never achieve Wn[1] <= 0 because of the conditions I explained in my previous comment. You can change the initial value or the randomization factor and remove the prints when debug is finished to see the desired output.

Comment: @Bob Consider accepting the answer if it was useful.