# Accepting the specific value of parameters with repeating the step of loop

Tags: python, while-loop

Is there any way if the below `condition` is not satisfied, Python repeats the calculation of that step? we cannot remove outputs containing negative value of `om`. We have to repeat that step with different random number which led to negative value. `N` is 1000 and we must have 1000 outputs.

`condition: if mo[i]<0 repeat the calculation until we have mo[i]>0 for each step`

```
#initial values
mo  = np.zeros((1000,))
mo[0]=0.24
mn = np.zeros((1000,))
Wo  = np.zeros((1000,))
Wo[0]=0.2
Wn = np.zeros((1000,))

def F( x, y):
    return....

N=1001
for i in range (1,N):
    R=np.random.uniform(0,1)

    mn[i] = mo[i-1] + 0.05 * np.random.normal()
    Wn[i] = Wo[i-1] + 0.05 * np.random.normal()

    L = exp(-0.5 * ( F(mn[i], Wn[i] ) - F( mo[i-1], Wo[i-1])))

    if L>R:
        Wo[i]=Wn[i]
        mo[i]=mn[i]

    else:
        Wo[i]=Wo[i-1]
        mo[i]=mo[i-1]

    print(Wo[i],mo[i])
```

This question is in the following of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49916212/using-while-loop-to-repeat-a-step-of-loop-to-reach-the-proper-answer?answertab=active#tab-top)

Answer (score 1):

Use a while loop with a break statement

```
for i in range(1,N):
    while True:
        mo[i] = get_mo_i()

        if mo[i] > 0:
            break
```

where `get_mo_i()` should be replaced by everything in your current loop. I just didn't feel like typing it all out

if you are worried about your code not ending, you can set a limit on how often the loop may reiterate

```
for i in range(1,N):
    num = 0
    while True:
        num += 1
        mo[i] = get_mo_i()

        if mo[i] > 0 or num > 10:
            break
```

The above one will have `mo[i]` stay negative, only if it got a negative value `10` times in a row. That indicates you might have issues with initial conditions, or simply that `mo[i-1]` ended up with a value that is unlikely to create positive `mo[i]`.

Comment: could the value of `num>10` be changed? for example: `>100` . Would changes in this value affect out outputs?

Comment: Sure, 10 was just an arbitrary number that I used. That said, looking at the code, if mo[i-1] is 0, and L<R, there is a 50% chance that mo[i] will be negative on each run. So if you have num>10, there will be a ~1/1024 chance of the loop failing due to random chance. Set num>30, it will be about 1 in a billion. If mo[i] is negative at that point, odds are you have an error somewhere else in the code. So don't set it too high. It will just make that part of the code run longer if there is a critical bug

Comment: Ah, so it doeas not matter whether we choose it 5 or 15. Generally it stays our value negative. Also we can add some other condition to it.`if mo[i] > 0 and Wo[i]<0 or num > 10:` is it correct to write it?

Comment: That is fine, though I would suggest adding parenthesis for clearer reading. `if (mo[i] > 0 and Wo[i] < 0) or num > 10:` for example would help someone else read your code.

Comment: thank you, I knew about `while` but without the `num` in your answer it does not work on my example. adding it, every thing work fine.

Comment: I don't know why, but after 4 times running the code, `mo` gets bothpositive and negative value.

Comment: in spite of `if (mo[i]<0.2 and mo[i]>0.32) or num>10:` it goes beyond `0.32` and `0.2`. why?

Comment: `(mo[i]<.2 and mo[i]>.32)` requires mo[i] to simultaneously be below 0.2 and above 0.32. I think you meant or: `if (mo[i]<0.2 or mo[i]>0.32) or num>10:` or you meant `if (mo[i]>0.2 and mo[i]<0.32) or num>10:`

Comment: I wrote `if mo[i]<0.2 or num>10:` but in out puts I had`mo=0.09`. again  I wrote `if mo[i]<0 or num>10:`, but I had `-0.9` in out puts I don't know why if the code is forcing Python to do them

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169327/discussion-between-david-l-and-bob).